What is the mean of expansion of $g(x)$ as $x\rightarrow -\infty$?
I see the following statement in a paper. I want to know what is the expansion of $g(x)$ as $x\rightarrow -\infty$. I know the Taylor expansion at $x_0$. But I seemly never see the Taylor expansion at $\infty$.

Now suppose we have a solution $g(x)$ where as $x\rightarrow -\infty$ we have an expansion
$$
g(x)= b e^{\lambda x} + c e^{2\lambda x} + \dots
$$
in power  of $e^{\lambda x}$ with no constant term.

Following is the origin of this problem. They are from 237- 262 of this paper.







Just a guess, is this something to do with high temperature expansion?

@Pranay Yes, sorry, I've made the edit.

If $\lambda$ is positive then the expansion only converges if $x$ is negative. Are there any other constraints to your problem? Perhaps you could give an example to clarify what you are asking.

Yes and also bring a context on the sequence $b$ , $c$ so !

Without knowing the exact context it’s not so clear but probably an ‘asymptotic expansion’ of some kind (see eg Wikipedia page of that name)

@Amogh I feel strange too. In fact, the author does not explain in detail.
